# Default Activity not found in downloaded derived APK

Tags: android, apk

I've published an app to Google Play which uses the "Let Google Sign the App" option (yeah, I'm a dummy for doing that). I've downloaded the derived APK from Play Console and imported into Android Studio. When I try to run it I get the "Default Activity not found" error.

The manifest has a default activity specified (See below). I've tried clearing cache, changing run config to "None" activity, etc.

All ideas are welcome!

```
<activity
    android:theme="@ref/0x0103000a"
    android:label="@ref/0x7f090014"
    android:name="com.godot.game.GodotApp"
    android:launchMode="2"
    android:screenOrientation="1"
    android:configChanges="0x1ff0"
    android:resizeableActivity="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Just discovered this appears to be a problem with Android Studio 4.0. I tried loading a previously functioning APK and now get the same problem, Default Activity not found. Suspect this may have to do with the APK's generated by Godot Android export.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in ASv4.0 or incompatibility between Godot Android export template and ASv4.0.

Downgraded to ASv3.6.3 and all is good.

If you are using Godot to build Android apps, recommend you do not upgrade Android Studio to v4.0